# How do I determine which polygon feature with an SDO_geometry doesn't partially overlap a polyline feature with an SDO_geometry?

Tags: fme-form, oracle-spatial, smallworld-gis

I have 2 datasets in the Oracle spatial format, built from Smallworld data;

1. One with polygon features
2. One with polyline features.

I'm looking to determine which polygon features do not contain (part of) a polyline feature, but the Smallworld application the organization uses has just been redeveloped and doesn't really allow spatial queries yet.

Both features have an SDO_geometry attribute, but I'm a bit stuck on how exactly to approach the comparison. Both are pretty massive datasets (>1.000.000 records each), so I'm thinking FME should be able to be faster than an Oracle query, but I might just be overthinking it. How should I go about this comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be under the impression that FME is going to be faster than an Oracle Query. It certainly depends on the query, and I have found that database operations are often much faster than FME.  However, FME has the tools you need to complete this job. Provided you have the correct [licenses](https://www.safe.com/pricing/fme-desktop/) to read Oracle/Smallworld datasets, this should be a fairly straightforward operation in FME.

The first thing you want to do is read both datasets into FME. Then, connect them to a spatial filter. Connect your polygon features to the candidate port and the polyline features to the filter port.

Set your Spatial Predicates to Test to either "Filter Intersects Candidate" and use the features that exit the "Failed" port, or set it to "Filter is Disjoint from Candidate" and use the "Passed" port.

[image]

Comment: I belive the assumption is that - because they haven't got the Smallworld application up and running, they won't have to 'connect' their FME session through a Smallworld application - which means they shouldn't need an FME Smallworld license......also I have had some issues with FME and tolerances in the past, so be mindful of this when performing spatial queries.

Comment: Yes, OP mentions they have the data in Oracle. They'll still need the Database edition to read Oracle. Good tip regarding tolerances.

Comment: It looks like FME introduced the concept of Tolerance in FME 2018 see 
 here - (https://www.safe.com/blog/category/tolerance/) -